# python Parralize inside a function and return a dictionary

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use python multiprocessing and return a dictionary. The difficulty is I hope this multiprocessing inside a function and return the final value. Is that possible? Here is my current try.

```
def main_function(G):
    def f(d,n):
       d[n] = another_function(G)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       manager = Manager()
       d = manager.dict()
       job = [Process(target=f, args=(d, i)) for i in G]
       _ = [p.start() for p in job]
       _ = [p.join() for p in job]

       return d

expected_value = main_function(G)
```

But it does not work at all. The function will not go after the '`if __name__...`'. Hence the return value is None.

Also, the goal is to use the return value in another function. Such as

```
def final_function(G):
    dictionary = main_function(G)
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
         target = ....
    return target

finally = final_function(G)
```

Is there any way I can solve it? I do need this Parralize run inside the main_function.

Answer (score 0):

You are 99% correct but I have seen people making mistakes of putting `if __name__ == '__main__':` in wrong place.

I have added the working code with comments.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
from multiprocessing.context import Process


# take out your `f` because the newly created process wont have access to this method if it resides within `main_function`. 
# I have replaced your `another_function` call to square of number.
def f(d, n):
    d[n] = n ** 2

# take out if main == name check.
def main_function(G):
    manager = Manager()
    d = manager.dict()
    job = [Process(target=f, args=(d, i)) for i in G]
    _ = [p.start() for p in job]
    _ = [p.join() for p in job]

    return d

# put it here..
if __name__ == '__main__':
    expected_value = main_function(list(range(1, 11)))
    print(expected_value)
```

**Output**

```
{1: 1, 5: 25, 4: 16, 2: 4, 7: 49, 3: 9, 6: 36, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the real problem is the code is inside a big project. There is actually another function call this main_function(),  this function uses a for loop to get the values of this dictionary. And then another function call that function. In that case, where should I put this {__name__ == '__main__'} ?

Comment: what kind of project is this? web api using flask or something else? I have not done multiprocessing for prod apps but if I get how the app is being started I might be able to tell where the `name` check should be put.

Comment: Hi, it's another python package that does not initially support parallel computation. I was trying to modify a part of it so I can use parallel computing. That package named 'networkx' if you are interested. I tried to illustrate the problem as above. Where should I put the 'name' in this case? (I edited the original problem).

Answer (score 0):

I have done a little search and realize the `if __name__=='main`is only required for Windows. So I removed this line and run it on a Linux server. It looks fine. I am feeling parralization on Linux is much easier than Windows.